# Update Hangs @ Configuring Shim Signed

Tags: uefi, update-manager

Any update I run, the update is hanging at "configuring shim signed". I've just been closing the window and moving on and haven't seen a problem yet, but am scared it will come. I am a dual-booting W10/Ubuntu 16.04 computer using UEFI. Anybody have a clue how to fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. When I tried to run update from terminal

`sudo apt update`

I got a message:

*dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.*

After running the suggested command

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

with default answers & reboot, the problem has been fixed.